# Compare directories ignoring time differences of 1h +- 2s

Tags: rsync, file-comparison, meld

I often want to synchronize my Music folders between my Android mobile phone and my Linux PC. The files on my phone are stored on an SD card using FAT32 and can come from either my Windows laptop or my Linux desktop PC. I want to compare only metadata, otherwise it takes ages to compare contents.

When I use Meld or rsync to find differences, I get a lot of false positives caused by the fact that FAT32 stores file times with 2-second resolution and local time (UK time), whereas on Linux file modification times are stored with sub-second resolution and UTC. So when I am looking at a file copied to SD card during winter and now it's summer, or vice versa, I can see a time difference of exactly 1 hour (with 2-second precision).

Is there a tool that will scan the folders and consider the file times to be the same if they differ by 2 seconds OR by between 59m58s and 1h00m02s ?

Comment: Someone suggested `rsync --modify-window` but it seems the post has been deleted. I can't see why, as it's exactly what I'd have suggested too. If it's not undeleted and no-one else pips me to it I'll explain how you can use this option to address your requirement

Comment: Any chance you might want to run the sync on the phone?  FolderSync can run on android, is pretty fast, and can talk with several services (FTP/SFTP/SMB likely the easiest for Linux).   I haven't noticed any of the above issues when syncing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rsync` you could ignore times altogether with `--ignore-times`.

Or allow the timestamps to differ by a certain amount of seconds (in your case 3602, an hour + two seconds) with `--modify-window=3602` (note that files with timestamps differing by half an hour would also fall in that window).

A third option is to ignore times as above (you could also only consider just the size with `--size-only`) and force a checksum calculation with `--checksum`.

Comment: Thanks. The modify-window option is not _exactly_ what I'm after as a difference is significant if it is 59m57s, or 1h00m03s, but insignificant if it is 59m58s or 1h00m02s. However, since rsync is already present on most Linux systems, I'll take your answer as a reasonable compromise.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--modify-window` option of [rsync](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) to flatten the 2-second resolution:

> ```
>   --modify-window=NUM, -@
>        When comparing two timestamps, rsync treats the timestamps
>        as being equal if they differ by no more than the modify-
>        window value.  The default is 0, which matches just
>        integer seconds.  If you specify a negative value (and the
>        receiver is at least version 3.1.3) then nanoseconds will
>        also be taken into account.  Specifying 1 is useful for
>        copies to/from MS Windows FAT filesystems, because FAT
>        represents times with a 2-second resolution (allowing
>        times to differ from the original by up to 1 second).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fdupes`, which is a command-line program that can find and delete duplicate files. It has an option to ignore differences in modification times by a specified number of seconds. To use `fdupes`, you can run the following command:

```
fdupes -r -S -T2m /path/to/directory1 /path/to/directory2
```

This will recursively search the two directories for duplicate files while ignoring time differences of up to 2 minutes.

You can also use `dirsyncpro` (which is a cross-platform program for synchronizing and backing up files and folders), create a new profile, and set the source and destination directories. Then, go to the "Options" tab and select "Compare Options". Under the "Time" section, you can select the "Ignore time differences" option and set the range to be between 59m58s and 1h00m02s.